# Shared array between multiple classes

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I have an array "myArr" which contains objects of custom class..e.g. objs of type MyClass

I need to share this array across multiple classes..

Could you please help me with the exact code that I should be using..

I have referred Singleton patter on Apple and other references, but it is all ver confusing to me...So it will be great if you could highlight the things/code that I need to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you read up on object delegation.

> @property (nonatomic,copy) NSArray *myArr;

On your other classes, implement a delegate object that will point to this class, then you could use:

> NSArray *retrievedArray = [self.delegate myArr];

Edit: If you are interested to use only Singleton i believe it would be something along this way:

> static MyClass *obj = nil;

On your class with the array, create a class method to return a Singleton object

> +(MyClass*) sharedInstance {
>
> ```
>      if (obj) {
>
>       obj = [[self alloc]init];
>
>      }
> ```
>
> return obj;
>
> }

On your other classes you could just use

> NSArray *retrievedArray = [[MyClass sharedInstance] myArr];

to get back the array.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the Singleton info...It is exactly along the lines that I am looking for. I have implemented as per your comments. But still there seems to be some problem (I mean there is no error as such), but things are not working the way I want to.

Is there any way that I could check while debugging that the instance is indeed acting as Singleton?

Comment: hi..thanks..Singleton seems to be working fine now..But the issue is with something else..thx for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

I’d [stay away from singletons](http://zmotula.tumblr.com/post/1390385240/why-singletons-suck). As the array is some kind of model (in the Model–View–Controller sense), other classes should depend on it:

```
@interface ControllerA : UIViewController {}
@property(retain) NSArray *array;
@end

@interface ControllerB : UIViewController {}
@property(retain) NSArray *array;
@end
```

Now the question changes into “how do I supply the depency.” You can do this using Interface Builder or supply the array when the depending objects are built. For example I sometimes have a method called `setupObjectGraph` in my application delegate that creates class instances and connects them together:

```
- (void) setupObjectGraph
{
    mainController = [[MainController alloc] init…];
    [mainController setThis…];
    [mainController setThat…];

    OtherController *bar = [[OtherController alloc] init…];
    [bar setThis…];
    [bar setThat…];
    [mainController setBar:bar];
    [bar release];

    …
}

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunchingOrWhatever
{
    [self setupObjectGraph];
    [window addSubview:[mainController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

This is not perfect (it does not scale very well), but it works for many applications and it’s much better than singletons. This sounds like a trifle issue, but it affects your overall design a lot, so it makes sense to think it through.

Comment: Actually I would want to stay away from app delegate..I had used app delegate for global var, but it was not behaving consistently. I mean not sure if there was some release issue, But I m looking for a soln using Singleton.

Comment: This is not using the application delegate for storing global data, the application delegate is only used as a nice place to set up the whole object graph, connect all the dependencies. If you insist on using a singleton, I’m sure somebody will post a solution using just that. Or you can search previous questions, there’s a plenty information about using singletons in Objective-C.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for using Singleton. I already searched a lot on Singleton, but am totally confused with the correct approach and hence am looking for someone to help. Thanks.